# Add text field elements to a div's style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styling

I want to add the text from a text field onto another div's style attribute.

For example, there is an input on the page:

```
<input id="text" />
```

and a div on the page:

```
<div id="div1" stlye="background:"></div>
```

I want what the user inputs in the text_field to show in that div's style. So if a user types the string `#FF0000`, then I want (in realtime) for the div's style attribute to change to

```
<div id="div1" style="background:#FF0000"></div>
```

How can I accomplish this with JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#text').keyup(function () {
    $("#div1").css('background', $('#text').val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yea I understand how to change the inner HTML of the div, I'm just trying to change the style attribute of that div :)

Comment: Nice @Adosi, that works great. I'll accept the answer when it allows me too

Answer (score 0):

Use the change() function like so

```
$('#inp').keyup(function () {
$("#div1").css('background', $('#inp').val());
});
```

with keyup

http://jsfiddle.net/NVW4S/1/

with change
http://jsfiddle.net/NVW4S/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the jQuery `on` function:

```
$('#text').on('keyup', function () {
    $("#div1").css('background', $(this).val());
});
```

Furthermore, using the same selector instead of `this` is impractical.